# Processing.js FloatList doesn't work on web

Tags: javascript, arraylist, floating-point, processing, processing.js

My processing.js sketch uses [FloatList](https://processing.org/reference/FloatList.html) and it works when I build it with Sublime. However, when I try to run it on a web page, the sketch doesn't load and I get `Uncaught Processing.js: Unable to execute pjs sketch: ReferenceError: FloatList is not defined` from the javascript console. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Any suggestions and help would be gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the error says it all: Processing.js does not have a `FloatList` class. You can confirm this by checking out [the Processing.js reference](http://processingjs.org/reference/).

I'm not sure why Processing.js didn't implement the `FloatList` class. Maybe because JavaScript arrays are so different than Java arrays. That's just a guess though. [Here](https://github.com/processing-js/processing-js/issues/238) is an open issue about this on Processing.js's GitHub page. [Here](https://github.com/processing-js/processing-js/issues/159) is another issue that shows which classes have been implemented. `FloatList` is indeed not yet implemented.

In any case, you're going to have to modify your code to get rid of the `FloatList` class.

Of course, Processing.js is open source. So you could always add the `FloatList` class yourself! You might even be able to copy much of [the source](https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/master/core/src/processing/data/FloatList.java) directly.

Comment: I changed the `FloatList` class to `ArrayList<Float>` and changed a few of its methods and it worked on my [website](http://brandonlou.github.io/Lightning). Thanks!

Comment: @Brandon No problem. Cool project!